# kohana 3 + swift mailer

Tags: php, kohana

i'm using swift mailer from github for kohana framework 3, on localhost i have no troubles, but when i use it on hoster server it throws an error:

Fatal error: Class 'Swift_DependencyContainer' not found in ***/application/vendor/swift/dependency_maps/cache_deps.php on line 3

how can i bypass it?

Comment: doh sorry its my stupid, i've uploaded files with ftp manager and he lowercased all names

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hay bro, u may try http://github.com/banks/kohana-email instead of using Swift Mailer directly.

Comment: thanks, but it was my fault - i used total commander which by default renames to lowercase all uploaded files. after removing this option all is ok. btw thx!